# Enabling https in moqui framework with tomcat

Tags: tomcat8, moqui

I have a Tomcat server with SSL configured. in server.xml my config is:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443"
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       maxThreads="100"
       compression="on"
       scheme="https"
       SSLEnabled="true"
       secure="true"
       defaultSSLHostConfigName="test.com">
<SSLHostConfig hostName="test.com"
               protocols="TLSv1.2">
    <Certificate certificateKeyFile="/opt/tomcat/cert/PrivateKey.pem"
                 certificateFile="/opt/tomcat/cert/Cert.pem"
                 certificateChainFile="/opt/tomcat/cert/Chain.pem" />
</SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

and also my config for moqui is:

```
<default-property name="webapp_http_host" value="test.com"/>
<default-property name="webapp_http_port" value="8080"/>
<default-property name="webapp_https_port" value="8443"/>
<default-property name="webapp_https_enabled" value="true"/>
```

when I start the tomcat server, the Moqui framework started successfully, but when I type the URL in the browser nothing happened.
what should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you hit the URL? Or is there no listener on the port. Can you post a URL that you're using and what exactly is returned (is there a 404, 503 error, or an SSL handshake error).

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply, I checked the port '8443' and it is running. the browser response message is 'This site can’t be reached'

Comment: is there something about network or nginx config?

Comment: If the server is running on another machine, you should check the firewalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, everything is correct just give access to port 8443 with firewall.
Thanks

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8443/tcp --permanent success 
# firewall-cmd --reload success
# iptables-save | grep 8443 -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Please, accept your answer (the checkmark beside the answer).